# How to select all values that do not have a specific relationship?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with a Student table and a Course table with an M to M relationship.  I need to select all students that are not taking a specific course.  How can I do this sort of negative condition?

Comment: Can you post your table definitions?  Use a `LEFT JOIN` of the `Student` to `Course` table, and retain student records which do _not_ match to any course.

Comment: How would you select all students that *are* taking a specific course?

Comment: [Not](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/logical-operators.html#operator_not).

Comment: How are you tracking which courses are being taken by which students and / or vice versa?  Are you using an intermediate table or some other technique?

Comment: Please give as much information as possible about your situation & what you have tried. Please read the links [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) about asking questions..

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways:

use an `outer join`:

```
select s.student_id
  from student s
  left join course c
    on s.student_id = c.student_id
   and c.course_id = 'xyz'
 where c.student_id is null;
```

use a `not exists` subquery:

```
select student_id
  from student s
 where not exists (select 1
          from course c
         where c.student_id = s.student_id
           and c.course_id = 'xyz');
```

use a `not in` subquery:

```
select student_id
  from student
 where student_id not in (select student_id from course where course_id = 'xyz');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with

- NOT EXISTS and a correlated subquery; i.e., select all students where there does not exist a relationship to the specific course
- IN and an uncorrelated subquery; i.e., select all students that are not in the set of students that have a relationship to the specific course
- OUTER JOIN and a filter where the course name is NULL; i.e. select all students and their relationship, if any, to the specific course, and filter out the ones that are taking the course.

and probably other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this query ?

```
    SELECT * FROM Student a WHERE a.M NOT IN (SELECT b.M FROM Course b WHERE)
```